# Use static library that has a lot of custom dependencies (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, static-libraries

I have a static library `libSth.a` that has custom dependencies and is implemented as a class.

I link the library when the program compiles without any errors. However, when I import the library's header file to make a object of the library class and use the functions inside the program code, it gets error because of the dependencies inside the static library. The dependencies inside the library are a lot so I can't always import all of the dependencies inside my main program.

How can I fix this problem and be able to use the static library?

I've been stuck for a week on this, I'd really appreciate it if any one helps!

Comment: You need to link with the transitive dependencies of that library.

Comment: Linkers are simple. If you link and do not use a lib, it will ignore the symbols related to the library and not bother to check its dependencies.

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean about "importing" dependencies.  That's not a C++ concept.  Your header should contain *`#include`* directives for any other headers required to understand the your header's contents.  When you build a program that uses your library you need also to *link* other libraries on which it depends.